# Method with Generic Type Parameter "deserialize to string"

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I've got this non working method. Where the type, T,  can sometimes be "string". Of course the deserialization doesn't make sense, so I would like to check if T is a string and return the result before deserialization. How can I obtain this?

```
private T SendRequest<T, E>(string url, E body, Guid? token)
    {
        var request           = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method        = body != null ? "POST" : "GET";
        request.ContentType   = "application/json";
        if (token != null)
        {
            request.Headers.Add("Token", token.ToString());
        } 

        if (body != null)
        {
            var bodyWriter = new StringWriter();
            _serializer.Serialize(new JsonTextWriter(bodyWriter), body);

            var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(bodyWriter.ToString());

            request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

            using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }
        }

        using (var response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (var responseStreamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var str = responseStreamReader.ReadToEnd();

                if (typeof(T) == typeof(String))
                {
                    return str; // <-- Cannot convert expression type 'string' to return type 'T'
                }

                return _serializer.Deserialize<T>(new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(str)));
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you know `T` is `string` at that point, I know, also the "Runtime"(CLR) knows but poor compiler doesn't know it is string.

To make it work you need to cast it to `T`

```
return (T)(object)str;
```

Note: cast to `object` is required since you cant directly cast string to `T`.

Comment: Right. Thank you! Can't believe how quick you can get an answer here :)

Comment: This one is not that fast, sometimes you'll get answer in few seconds :)

Comment: Ha ha. OK, but fast enough for me anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Since the compiler can't check if you can convert a `string` to `T`, you need to cast the `string` into an `object` first:

```
return (T)(object)str;
```

It works because you can always cast from `string` to `object`, and also from `object` to anything. Altough it can fail at run-time if the underlying type is not the same.